# Rich Text Box Hyperlink does not work in MS Access 2016 Split Form Datasheet Section

Tags: microsoft-access, hyperlink, forms

I am using a Split Form which has a Rich Text box containing HTML formatted hyperlinks to certain files on my local computer. Everything is working fine except that when I open the Split form in "Form view" (Form on top and Datasheet on bottom), the hyperlinks on the Datasheet section do not seem to work. In every other display format (such as Datasheet only view, Layout view etc.) the links are working fine. I have no clue what the underlying issue is. Probably the Datasheet section in Split form has some different properties than the Datasheet only view. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are any errors displayed? Are you able to share any code for these links?

Comment: There are no errors or any code. It's just that in that particular Split Form Datasheet section the hyperlinks in the Rich Text box do not work as they do in every other form view.